# Redirect webpage (wordpress) at given time/date

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm looking for a way (maybe inside wordpress) to change the the `url:www.website1.eg` of the website to another `url:www.website2.eg` at a certain date/time `e.g 23 december at 12:34 AM`.

Is there a plugin in which i can set the redirect at any given time/date, or do i need to script something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scheduler to move the Wordpress files from a hidden folder on the ftp to live site at a set time: http://www.serv-u.com/kb/1035/using-the-ftp-voyager-scheduler

Just ensure the database is already uploaded and ready to link to the new files.